# How can I get the Subscription Name if i know the resource Group Name using Powershell

Tags: powershell, subscription

So, I have the resource Group name and i want to programmatically (using powershell) set the subscription to the incoming resource group.
When i do a `Get-AzResourceGroup` I get the ResourceId which contains the the subscription id as part of a long string `/subscriptions/<subscription id here>/resourceGroups/resourcegroupname`. Is there a way to extract the subscription Id from that string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get your subscription ID by triggering the below. You will also need to have azure cli installed.

```
az account list  --refresh --query "[?contains(name, 'YOUR_SUBSCRIPTION')].id"
```

You can also split the output from `powershell`.

```
$myinput= "/subscriptions/xxxxxx-xxxxxx-xxxxxx-xxxxx-xxxxxx/resourceGroups/resourcegroupname".Split("/")

Write-Host $myinput[2]
```

Comment: Thank you! That worked